# Which one is correct : "The movie is well received." or "The movie is well-received."?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation

Can we hyphenate predicative adjective?

I learnt that usually we don't hyphenate predicate adjective.
For example, He is well known.

However, for the word "well-received" , which is listed in the online dictionary of Collin, has several examples sentences showing that this is possible.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-received

e.g.
The film was not well-received by critics initially.
The Sun (2016)

Is it because the verb is in passive voice hence making it acceptable to put a hyphen between?

Comment: The dictionary entry you cite answers your question. It says "well-received" before the noun (their example is "his well-received books"), but it adds a note: "**well received** when postpositive". There are a varied of *automatically-generated* usage examples later on the page, but because they're automatically generated, they are less trustworthy.

Comment: They're both fine. Hyphens are an optional punctuation, and are usually replaced in printing with n dashes anyway. Use them any way you please. Everyone else does.

Comment: @JohnLawler Than-k you for permission to-use them like-this.

Comment: It's your language, and your writing style.

Comment: A newcomer question that is researched and poses subtleties of meaning that are not merely matters of opinion, although in practice there is little difference. I see no reason for the downvote so have remedied it. Leave open.